# Excel: счет по двум критериям (функция СЧЕТЕСЛИ?)

Tags: excel

Например есть таблица с двумя колонками:

VRT | 1
VRT | 1
VRT | 2
DMT | 1
DMT | 5
TIM | 2
TIM | 4
TIM | 5
VRT | 3
DMT | 1
DMT | 2
TIM | 2

Мне нужно посчитать сколько цифр по каждому блоку. Например, сколько 1 и 2 у VRT, сколько 5 у DMT и т.д.

Результат должен быть вот таким:
VRT1 = 2 шт
VRT2 = 1 шт
VRT3 = 1 шт
DMT1 = 2 шт
DMT5 = 1 шт
DMT2 = 1 шт
TIM2 = 2 шт
TIM4 = 1 шт
TIM5 = 1 шт

Как это сделать?

Comment: может лучше воспользоваться сводной таблицей?

Comment: мне нужно каждую раздельно посчитать, например сколько однерок у VRT и так по каждому я сделаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше пользоваться сводными таблицами для таких задач.

Если хотите для конкретной пары то просто вот так ($A$1:$A$12 и $B$1:$B$12- столбец значений) :

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН($A$1:$A$12;"VRT";$B$1:$B$12;1)
```

Вот вариант через `СЧЁТЕСЛИМН` для всех пар

1) делаем таблицу уникальных пар 
-- копируем всю таблицу 
-- удаляем дубликаты ( Данные-> Удалить дубликать)

2) Делаем `СЧЁТЕСЛИМН` для каждой уникальной пары :
`=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН($A$1:$A$12;H1;$B$1:$B$12;I1)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уау, получилось! спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Многие пользуются *Excel-2003*, где нет *СЧЕТЕСЛИМН*.

Вариант замены недостающей функции:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--($A$2:$A$13="VRT");--($B$2:$B$13=1))
```

С доп. столбцом, где сцеплены данные (*=A2&B2*):

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($C$2:$C$13;C2)
```

С наличием сцепленных данных можно отобрать уникальные формулой:

```
=ИНДЕКС($C$2:$C$13;МИН(ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($E$3:E3;$C$2:$C$13)=0;СТРОКА($C$2:$C$13)-1)))
```

Формула массива, вводится одновременным нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*

Без доп. столбца тоже можно, но формула сложнее.

А если уникальные отобраны, то и считать просто.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желтый диапазон: ниже уникальных будет повтор первого уникального значения. Для устранения формулу нужно усложнять.